# TextInput focus blurring when first clicked

Tags: react-native

There was no issue before I tried to implement the handleInputBlur and handleInputFocus functions (Used to change the background when in focus). When I first click on the TextInput it comes into focus, but then immediately blurs, resulting in the background flashing then disappearing. What's strange is that after this first click, the future clicks work absolutely fine, focusses and blurs as it should. I do not understand why on the initial click/focus it immediately blurs. Code below:

EDIT: Bit more context, it's inside of a modal, which contains multiple of these editable items.

```
  class EditableItem extends Component {


    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        const { value } = this.props
        this.state = {
          value,
          isFocused: null,
        }
      }

      handleInputBlur = () => {
        this.setState({ isFocused: false })
        console.log('blurring')
      }

      handleInputFocus = () => {
        this.setState({ isFocused: true })
        console.log('focussing')
      }

  render() {
    const { name, secure, children, autoCapitalize } = this.props
    const { value, isFocused } = this.state
    const multiline = !secure

    return (
      <View>
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <Text style={styles.name}>{name}</Text>
          <View style={isFocused ? styles.activeBackground : styles.unfocusedBackground}>
            <TextInput
              placeholder={name}
              placeholderTextColor={COLOR_BASE_3}
              underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
              style={styles.value}
              secureTextEntry={secure}
              value={value}
              // blurOnSubmit
              onSubmitEditing={() => {
                Keyboard.dismiss()
              }}
              returnKeyType="done"
              keyboardAppearance="dark"
              autoCapitalize={autoCapitalize}
              onChangeText={this.onChange}
              multiline={multiline}
              onBlur={() => this.handleInputBlur()}
              onFocus={() => this.handleInputFocus()}
            />

            {children}
          </View>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.divider} />
      </View>
    )
  }

  onChange = value => {
    const { onChange } = this.props
    this.setState({ value })
    onChange(value)
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you set the initial focused state to `null` instead of `false`?

Comment: @BarryMichaelDoyle forgot I left that as null - no reason other than act of desperation trying to get this to work, doesn't solve anything when initialised as false

Comment: Yeah I didn't it would solve it, was just a slight hunch. Not sure how to help you, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so solved this by setting `autofocus` to true in the TextInput. Not sure why not having this set causes this issue but it's a solution regardless.